# what does "In a handy module" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm trying to translate this sentence:

```
This focused review encompasses an overview on alkaline proteases, mainly of
microbial sources in a handy module.
```

but I can't understand what does "in a handy module" mean.

Comment: It simply means it is not an overwhelming review; it is only a dozen pages long and it implies that all the best ideas of the nine authors are well represented.

Comment: "Module" simply means "package".  The above is a hair ambiguous, but I take it to mean that the document being described is compact (only a few pages) and makes a good introduction or reference work.

Comment: It's from the University of Calcutta and appears in an open-source (likely not peer-reviewed) journal.  From the perspective of AmE/BrE, It has many nonstandard usages.  The paper contains several handy tables classifying the various types of proteases.  Perhaps one these is the handy module or perhaps @HotLicks is right and the entire paper is the module.

Comment: @deadrat - Yeah, reading it cold one wonders if the proteases are the "handy modules".  It's not surprising that Opie had trouble with it.

Comment: @Taxellool No, no, don' t delete the question.  It's a valid one.  I didn't post an answer because I'm not sure enough of the guesses in my comment.  This may be a commonly-used term in Indian English, and I'm not conversant (so to speak)  enough in that variant to be taken as a reliable source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential interpretations jump out at me:

> This focused review encompasses an overview on alkaline proteases,
>   mainly of
>   **microbial sources in a handy module**.

or

> This focused review encompasses **an overview on alkaline proteases**,
>   mainly of microbial sources, **in a handy module**.

Perhaps there is some technical jargon about microbial sources in modules, but that sounds very awkward and I doubt it.

I'm pretty sure they meant the second case, and just missed an important comma.  In this case, they're just saying that the overview is provided in a handy module - i.e. in an easy-to-use package format.